# Weyl group, permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

Let $U(n)$ be the unitary group and $T$ its maximal torus (group of diagonal matrix) and $N(T)$ the normalizer of $T$ in $G$. Why $N(T)/T$ is the permutation group $S_{n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: To compute $N(T)$ easily, note that if $D$ is a diagonal matrix, and $U$ is a matrix such that $U^{-1}DU$ is also diagonal, then $U$ must take eigenvectors of $D$ to other eigenvectors of $D$.  (Remember that conjugation = change of basis.)

Comment: I found $N(T)$ but I fail the identification of $S_{n}$ with $N(T)/T$...

Comment: Can you describe the matrices of $N(T)$ in words?  That should suggest a map $N(T) \to S_n$.

Comment: There are some $e^{i\theta}$ in diagonal anti-diagonl...

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Try writing down all the matrices of $N(T)$ for some small values of $n$.

Comment: There are matrix of permutation but they have non necessary $1$ at the entries...

Comment: Even though the entries aren't necessarily 1, you still have a map $N(T) \to S_n$.  Now look at the kernel of this map.

Comment: Only $0$ is in the kernell...?

Comment: I can't find an explicit isomorfism...