# Which is the Weyl group of $U(n)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, permutations, root-systems

Consider the unitary group $U(n)$.

How does one compute its Weyl group?

Is it the same as the Weyl group of $SU(n)$ since $U(n)\simeq SU(n)\times U(1)$?

Comment: The hints in this other answer may help: 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280502/weyl-group-permutation-group.